# How to install SQL Server 2005 Express with pre-existing SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have a 32-bit XP with VS 2008 and SQL Server 2008, both Full and Express databases.  I am trying to install SS 2005 Express and I get errors when I do saying that 2008 Express is a newer version.  How do I uninstall 2008 Express?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured this out.  I was confused.  After rerunning SS 2005 setup, it let me install it anyway.